# Problem with SelectInput and SliderInput in changing axis in scatterplot, R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a scatterplot where we can change the axis, and if a certain axis is selected, we have a sliderInput that permit to change the max and min of the axis. But I can't manage to do this. I have to use xlim and ylim with the input of the selectedInput, but if the selectedInput is not one of the ones that can be used with the sliderInput, it crashes. You will understand better with the code.

Here is my server side R :

```
#server.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- read.csv("../dataset/ds-final.csv")

members <- list("Alvaro", "Maxi", "Mikel")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$members <- renderText({
    paste("Authors:", paste(members, collapse = ", "))
  })
  
  output$selectedValues <- renderText({
    paste("Selected values:",
          "\nAge:", input$age[1], "-", input$age[2],
          ",\nGender:", input$gender,
          ",\nBMI:", input$bmi[1], "-", input$bmi[2],
          ",\nSymptoms:", ifelse(length(input$symptoms) > 0, paste(input$symptoms, collapse = ", "), "None"),
          ",\nWBC:", input$wbc[1], "-", input$wbc[2],
          ",\nRBC:", input$rbc[1], "-", input$rbc[2],
          ",\nHGB:", input$hgb[1], "-", input$hgb[2],
          ",\nPlatelet:", input$plat[1], "-", input$plat[2])
  })
  
  output$idiom1scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    x_axis <- sym(input$xaxis)
    y_axis <- sym(input$yaxis)
    
    # Check if "Age" is selected for X or Y axis
    if (x_axis == sym("Age")) {
      x_limits <- c(input$age[1], input$age[2])
    } else if (y_axis == sym("Age")) {
      y_limits <- c(input$age[1], input$age[2])
    }
    
    # Check if "BMI" is selected for X or Y axis
    if (x_axis == sym("BMI")) {
      x_limits <- c(input$bmi[1], input$bmi[2])
    } else if (y_axis == sym("BMI")) {
      y_limits <- c(input$bmi[1], input$bmi[2])
    }
    
    ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = !!x_axis, y = !!y_axis)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position = "top") +
      xlim(x_limits) +
      ylim(y_limits) +
      labs(title = paste("Scatterplot", input$xaxis, " vs ", input$yaxis), x = input$xaxis, y = input$yaxis)
  })
}
```

Here is the UI side :

```
library(shiny)

dataset <- read.csv("../dataset/HCV-Egy-Data.csv")

departament <- list("d1", "d2")

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("selectedValues"),
      fluidRow(
        style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
        helpText("1. Idiom."),
        plotOutput("idiom1scatterplot"),
      ),
      fluidRow(
        style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
        helpText("2. Idiom"),
      ),
      fluidRow(
        style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
        helpText("3. Idiom"),
      )
    )
)
```

Here is the app.R :

```
source("server.R")
source("ui.R")

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

BMI and Age are linked to sliderInputs. If I choose one of the two as a X or Y axis with the selectedInput, I want to be able to change the min and max of the axis with the sliderInput. But, if neither of them are selected, I still want to be able to see the plot. And also if only one of the two are selected.

Do not hesitate to ask any question if you didn't understand well the problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: As we cannot read your csv file, you should post the output of `dput(dataset)` in your question. A sample of 20 records should be fine.

Comment: You are reading `ds-final.csv` to the same dataset named `dataset`.  Perhaps you should consider giving it a different name.

Comment: Here is what I have when I do a dput(dataset) : 643305L, 988366L, 850944L, 435567L, 14653L, 730069L, 432094L, 
    1144203L, 665011L, 655686L, 484562L, 210705L, 1108462L, 1187255L, 
    654839L, 36310L, 166704L, 551247L, 374668L, 1014264L, 241929L, 
    613570L, 908440L, 850178L, 1150848L, 582741L, 670375L, 33911L,

Comment: Perhaps you can use one of the data frames available in `datasets` package (iris, rock, etc.) and modify your question.  Also, please remove all sliderInputs or selectInputs not relevant to answer your question.

Comment: What I want to do is to be able to use the sliderInput of an axis that I selected with a selectInput before, and use the xlim and ylim of this same sliderInput. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It is not possible to help you, if you don't provide sample data or make your app work with existing data.  Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here is a sample of the data : "Age","Gender","BMI","Fever","Nausea.Vomting","Headache","Diarrhea","Fatigue.generalized.bone.ache","Jaundice","Epigastric.pain","WBC","RBC","HGB","Platelet","AST.1","ALT.1","ALT.4","ALT.12","ALT.24","ALT.36","ALT.48","ALT.after.24.w","RNA.Base","RNA.4","RNA.12","RNA.EOT","RNA.EF","Baseline.histological.Grading","Baselinehistological.staging"
56,"1",35,"2","1","1","1","2","2","2",7425,4248807,14,112132,99,84,52,109,81,5,5,5,655330,634536,288194,5,5,13,2

Comment: 46,"1",29,"1","2","2","1","2","2","1",12101,4429425,10,129367,91,123,95,75,113,57,123,44,40620,538635,637056,336804,31085,4,2
57,"1",33,"2","2","2","2","1","1","1",4178,4621191,12,151522,113,49,95,107,116,5,5,5,571148,661346,5,735945,558829,4,4
49,"2",33,"1","2","1","2","1","2","1",6490,4794631,10,146457,43,64,109,80,88,48,77,33,1041941,449939,585688,744463,582301,10,3
59,"1",32,"1","1","2","1","2","2","2",3661,4606375,11,187684,99,104,67,48,120,94,90,30,660410,738756,3731527,338946,242861,11,1

Comment: 45,"2",25,"2","1","1","1","2","1","2",9279,4116937,13,203003,97,101,66,53,95,55,104,26,936444,536969,5,5,5,8,1
34,"1",22,"1","2","1","1","2","2","1",5638,4321603,14,141110,120,61,64,51,78,90,113,23,392976,884322,586834,182775,782154,9,2
40,"2",32,"2","2","2","1","2","1","1",11507,4165603,14,222874,127,122,106,105,88,111,111,36,1133727,1111871,421304,437544,124609,8,2

Answer (score 0):

Once you read in your dataset (your data has issues), you can try this

```
dataset <- read.csv("../dataset/HCV-Egy-Data.csv")

departament <- list("d1", "d2")


 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hepatitis Visualization App"),
  verbatimTextOutput("members"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xaxis", "X-axis", choices = c("BMI", "Baselinehistological.staging", "Baseline histological staging", "Age")),
    selectInput("yaxis", "Y-axis", choices = c("Baselinehistological.staging", "Baseline.histological.Grading", "BMI", "Age"), selected="Age"),
    sliderInput("age", "Age", min = min(as.numeric(dataset$Age)), max = max(as.numeric(dataset$Age)), value = c(as.numeric(min(dataset$Age)), max(as.numeric(dataset$Age)))),
    selectInput("gender", "Gender", choices = c("Male", "Female")),
    sliderInput("bmi", "BMI (Body Mass Index)", min = min(as.numeric(dataset$BMI)), max = max(as.numeric(dataset$BMI)), value = c(min(as.numeric(dataset$BMI)), max(as.numeric(dataset$BMI)))),
    checkboxGroupInput("symptoms", "Symptoms", choices = c("Fever", "Nausea/Vomiting", "Headache", "Diarrhea", "Fatigue and generalized", "Bone ache", "Jaundice", "Epigastric pain")),
    sliderInput("wbc", "WBC (White blood cell)", min = 299, max = 12101, value = c(299, 12101)),
    sliderInput("rbc", "RBC (Red blood cells)", min = 3816422, max = 5018451, value = c(3816422, 5018451)),
    sliderInput("hgb", "HGB (Hemoglobin)", min = 10, max = 15, value = c(10, 15)),
    sliderInput("plat", "Platelet", min = 93013, max = 226464, value = c(93013, 226464))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selectedValues"),
    fluidRow(
      style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
      helpText("1. Idiom."),
      plotOutput("idiom1scatterplot"),
    ),
    fluidRow(
      style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
      helpText("2. Idiom")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      style = "background-color: #F4F5F5;padding: 5px;",
      helpText("3. Idiom"),
    )
  )
)


members <- list("Alvaro", "Maxi", "Mikel")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$members <- renderText({
    paste("Authors:", paste(members, collapse = ", "))
  })

  output$selectedValues <- renderText({
    paste("Selected values:",
          "\nAge:", input$age[1], "-", input$age[2],
          ",\nGender:", input$gender,
          ",\nBMI:", input$bmi[1], "-", input$bmi[2],
          ",\nSymptoms:", ifelse(length(input$symptoms) > 0, paste(input$symptoms, collapse = ", "), "None"),
          ",\nWBC:", input$wbc[1], "-", input$wbc[2],
          ",\nRBC:", input$rbc[1], "-", input$rbc[2],
          ",\nHGB:", input$hgb[1], "-", input$hgb[2],
          ",\nPlatelet:", input$plat[1], "-", input$plat[2])
  })


  output$idiom1scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$xaxis,input$yaxis)
    x_axis <- input$xaxis
    y_axis <- input$yaxis

    # Check if "Age" is selected for X or Y axis
    if (x_axis == "Age") {
      x_limits <- c(as.numeric(input$age[1]), as.numeric(input$age[2]))
    } else if (x_axis == sym("BMI")) {
      x_limits <- c(as.numeric(input$bmi[1]), as.numeric(input$bmi[2]))
    } else { ## define x_limits for other variables
      x_limits <- c(0, 1000)
    }

    if (y_axis == "Age") {
      y_limits <- c(as.numeric(input$age[1]), as.numeric(input$age[2]))
    }else if (y_axis == "BMI") {
      y_limits <- c(as.numeric(input$bmi[1]), as.numeric(input$bmi[2]))
    }else { ##  define y_limits for other variables
      y_limits <- c(0, 1000)
    }

    p <- ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = as.numeric(.data[[input$xaxis]]), y = as.numeric(.data[[input$yaxis]]))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position = "top") +
      xlim(x_limits) +
      ylim(y_limits) +
      labs(title = paste("Scatterplot", input$xaxis, " vs ", input$yaxis), x = input$xaxis, y = input$yaxis)
    return(p)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: The issue happens if I select Baseline histological staging or grading as X or Y axis, since xlim or ylim won't be declared. It says "Error : objet 'x_limits' introuvable" or "Error : objet 'y_limits' introuvable".

Comment: Please check the updated code.  You should define x_axis and y_axis limits for other variables in your selectInputs.  Also, please avoid "dots" in variable names such as `bone.ache` or `ALT.1`, as it interferes with javascript.  Lastly, in your `selecInputs` for xaxis and yaxis, please ensure that the choices are limited to variables available in your dataframe.